# How do you deal with futures and mapAsync in Akka Flow?

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing, akka, akka-stream

I built a akka graph DSL defining a simple flow. But the flow f4 takes 3 seconds to send an element while f2 takes 10 seconds.

As a result, I got : 3, 2, 3, 2. But, this is not what I want. As f2 takes too much time, I would like to get : 3, 3, 2, 2. Here's the code...

```
implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("NumberSystem")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val in = Source(List(1, 1))
  val out = Sink.foreach(println)

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](2))



  val yourMapper: Int => Future[Int] = (i: Int) => Future(i + 1)
  val yourMapper2: Int => Future[Int] = (i: Int) => Future(i + 2)

  val f1, f3 = Flow[Int]
  val f2= Flow[Int].throttle(1, 10.second, 0, ThrottleMode.Shaping).mapAsync[Int](2)(yourMapper)
  val f4= Flow[Int].throttle(1, 3.second, 0, ThrottleMode.Shaping).mapAsync[Int](2)(yourMapper2)

  in ~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2 ~> merge ~> f3 ~> out
  bcast ~> f4 ~> merge
  ClosedShape
})
g.run()
```

So where am I going wrong ? With future or mapAsync ? or else ...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm new in akka, so I'm still learning. To get the expected results, one way is to put async :

```
val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  val in = Source(List(1, 1))
  val out = Sink.foreach(println)

  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val merge = builder.add(Merge[Int](2))



  val yourMapper: Int => Future[Int] = (i: Int) => Future(i + 1)
  val yourMapper2: Int => Future[Int] = (i: Int) => Future(i + 2)

  val f1, f3 = Flow[Int]
  val f2= Flow[Int].throttle(1, 10.second, 0, ThrottleMode.Shaping).map(_+1)
    //.mapAsyncUnordered[Int](2)(yourMapper)
  val f4= Flow[Int].throttle(1, 3.second, 0, ThrottleMode.Shaping).map(_+2)
    //.mapAsync[Int](2)(yourMapper2)

  in ~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2.async ~> merge ~> f3 ~> out
  bcast ~> f4.async ~> merge
  ClosedShape
})
g.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've already figured out, replacing:

```
mapAsync(i => Future{i + delta})
```

with:

```
map(_ + delta).async
```

in the two flows  would achieve what you want.

The different result boils down to the key difference between `mapAsync` and `map + async`.  While `mapAsync` enables execution of Futures in parallel threads, the multiple `mapAsync` flow stages are still being managed by the same underlying actor which would carry out [operator fusion](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#operator-fusion) before execution (for cost efficiency in general).

On the other hand, `async` actually introduces an asynchronous boundary into the stream flow with the individual flow stages handled by separate actors.  In your case, each of the two flow stages independently emits elements downstream and whichever element emitted first gets consumed first.  Inevitably there is a cost for managing the stream across the asynchronous boundary and Akka Stream uses a windowed buffering strategy to amortize the cost (see this [Akka Stream doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-rate.html)).

For more details re: difference between `mapAsync` and `async`, this [blog post](https://blog.colinbreck.com/maximizing-throughput-for-akka-streams/) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to join together the results coming out of f2 and f4. In which case you're trying to do what is sometimes called "scatter gather pattern".

I don't think there are off the shelf ways to implement it, without adding a custom stateful stage that will keep track of outputs from f2 and from f4 and emit a record when both are available. But they are some complications to bear in mind:

- What happens if a f2/f4 fails
- What happens if they take too long
- You need to have unique key for each input record, so you know which output from f2 correspond to f4 (or vice versa)